# Por que new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create() não funciona?

Tags: android

Já venho observando esse problema a algum tempo, e sempre tenho que manter uma instância a `Activity` atual, ao invés de manter apenas uma instância ao `Context`, e até então não entendi o por que, já que o método `AlertDialog.Builder(Context context)`, exige como parâmetro de inicialização apenas uma instância do `Context` e não da `Activity`.

Então se eu faço o seguinte código:

```java
AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create();
alert.setTitle("Title");
alert.setMessage("Message");
alert.show();
```

É gerado o seguinte erro em execução:

```
04-22 13:06:55.585: E/AndroidRuntime(3014): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.appteste/com.example.appteste.MainActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

Já se eu passo a `Activity` como parâmetro ao invés do `Context`, tudo funciona como o esperado:

```java
AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
alert.setTitle("Title");
alert.setMessage("Message");
alert.show();
```

Testei nas seguintes versões do Android: **4.0.3** e **4.4.2**

**Minhas duvidas são as seguintes:**

1. **Isso é um problema (Bug) do Android?**
2. **Estou fazendo algo de errado?**
3. **Por que isso acontece?**

> Obs: Para efeitos de testes, os códigos apresentados, foram executados dentro do método `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` da `Activity`.

Comment: Isto é mais uma de várias que o Android tem. Você não está a fazer nada de errado, desde que passe um Activity Context. Isto faz-me lembrar aquela frase do Ford: "Você pode escolher qualquer cor para o carro, desde que seja preta!"

Comment: @ramaral, então não há nada que um programador possa fazer? O Android está pedindo um `Context`, mas na verdade ele quer uma `Activity`, é isso que você quis dizer né? E terei que manter uma instância da Activity onde eu pretender chamar um   `AlertDialog`, sem choro certo?

Comment: Pela pequena pesquisa que fiz não há nada a fazer. Activity é um Context tal como ApplicationContext, mas parece que AlertDialog necessita mais do que um simples Context, necessita de algo que Activity acrescenta. Leia [isto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436822/why-does-alertdialog-buildercontext-context-only-accepts-activity-as-a-paramet)

Comment: @ramaral, lendo um pouco mais, me parece ser mais confuso que no inicio, por que diabos, eles fizeram uma estrutura dessa forma. Acredito, que se isso é um bug do Android, é um erro de Designer horrível, pois dificulta o entendimento de uma estrutura que poderia ser muito mais simples, e uma brecha para bugs, pois qualquer desenvolvedor desatento (como eu) pode criar um código que passe um `Context`, e se isso não for pego nos testes, poderá ir estourar no usuário final. Não entendo o por que dessa escolha pelos desenvolvedores do Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - **Isso é um problema (Bug) do Android?**

Aparentemente não: `getApplicationContext()` deve ser usado se você precisar de um contexto cujo ciclo de vida é separado do contexto atual , que está ligada ao tempo de vida do processo ao invés do componente atual. [Mais detalhes na documentação.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29)

2 - **Estou fazendo algo de errado?**

Provavelmente sim: Então como você está usando uma `Activity` e criando o seu `AlertDialog` dentro dela, o contexto desse alert será sua activity. [Baseado nesta resposta.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12471092/1873427)

3 - **Por que isso acontece?**

O raciocínio é que o `AlertDialog` não tem uma vida fora da sua `Activity`.

Sendo assim ele precisa do contexto em que foi criado, como o *getApplicationContext()* é diferente do *this* da sua activity você terá esse *Exception*.

Answer (score -1):

Este é um exemplo de um AlertDialog.

```
AlertDialog.Builder ADBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
ADBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
ADBuilder.setTitle("TÍTULO DO ALERTA");
ADBuilder.setMessage("MENSAGEM DO ALERTA");
ADBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // CÓDIGO QUE SERÁ EXECUTADO SE O USUÁRIO PRESSIONAR O BOTÃO SIM
    }
});
ADBuilder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // CÓDIGO QUE SERÁ EXECUTADO SE O USUÁRIO PRESSIONAR O BOTÃO NÃO
    }
});
ADBuilder.show();
```

Comment: Jhonas, obrigado pela atenção, mas minha duvida, não é de como criar um `AlertDialog`, mas sim sobre o problema(_bug_), ao passar o `getApplicationContext()` como parâmetro ao invés da `Activity`.

Comment: @JhonasKenneBoeno evite simplesmente postar o código. Mesmo que este já tenha sido reportado como insuficiente para a questão, elaborar uma resposta propriamente dita, detalhando processos, comentando o script e tudo o mais que se julgar necessário é de grande valia para a comunidade pois, hoje, pode não servir para ninguém, mas amanhã ou depois, algum usuário trazido pelo Google pode ter sua dúvida respondida antes mesmo de tê-la perguntado.

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que eu sei, não existe `getApplicationContext()` ou não é aplicável a `AlertDialog.Builder`. Tenta usar esse código minimizado feito por mim:

```
AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .create()
    .setTitle("titulo")
    .setMessage("msg")
    .setPositiveButton("funcao 1",
                       new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
       {
          @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface _dialog, int _which)
          {
             //codigo
          }
       })
    .show();
```